# How can I make a font awesome icon appear behind other text, as to emulate a background image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want the icon to appear centered horizontally and vertically behind the text.

I have tried numerous combinations of `position:absoulute`, `position:relative`, `z-index`, `display:flex`, but have not been able to acheive the wanted effect.

```
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="border rounded p-3 mb-4 overflow-hidden" style="height:200px;">
        <span class="fas fa-user-tie fa-3x fa-fw text-secondary"></span>
        <strong>Header</strong><br />
        Text text text text, etc.<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to give the parent container a `position:relative` for the children's `position:absolute` to work. Then wrap your icon in a different span to your text and make the positions absolute.

Eg; https://jsfiddle.net/L9cb8wao/

My fiddle is extremely rough, so apologies about that, however there should be enough there for you to fix your code accordingly to achieve what you're after.

Comment: I had to adjust the vertical position of the icon, because it was rendered at 50% (middle) from the top of the icon. When the icon is really big (`fa-x9`), that is important.

Comment: Yeah you would have had to make some minor tweaks and adjustments (as I said, it was a rough fiddle) but I'm glad it gave you what you needed to achieve your goal!